# IntegerReverse much slower than simple alternative

Tags: performance-tuning, system-performance

**Answered in comments.**

I find the built-in function `IntegerReverse[n]` is roughly an order of magnitude slower than the simple alternative `FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[n]]]`.

Tests were made with the following code:

```
testnumbers = Range[10^4];
(IntegerReverse /@ testnumbers;) // Timing
((FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]]&) /@ testnumbers;) // Timing
```

Version 11 gives:

```
{0.140625, Null}
{0.015625, Null}
```

Version 10 (on a different machine) gives:

```
{0.0625, Null}
{0.015625, Null}
```

This is a huge difference. I'm wondering if I'm missing a slowing feature of `IntegerReverse` or something like that.

Can anyone confirm this result? Should we report this to wolfram?

Comment: You may be interested in evaluating ``<<GeneralUtilities`; PrintDefinitions[IntegerReverse]`` to see the features and spot the differences.

Comment: Thanks. This answers the question. I did not thought, that this small overhead produces such a delay in evaluation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A substantial part of the timing difference in this example is due to the automatic compilation used by `Map`. Note the crossover setting

```
SystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength"]

(* {"CompileOptions" -> {"MapCompileLength" -> 100}} *)
```

and compare

```
testnumbers = Range[10^4];
AbsoluteTiming[Map[FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]] &, testnumbers];]

(* {0.006648, Null} *)
```

with

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "MapCompileLength" -> Infinity];   
AbsoluteTiming[Map[FromDigits[Reverse[IntegerDigits[#]]] &, testnumbers];]

(* {0.015754, Null} *)
```

The relevant part of the implementation of `IntegerReverse`, while straightforward and seemingly similar

```
Attributes[IntegerReverse] := {Listable, Protected, ReadProtected};
IntegerReverse[n_Integer] := With[{digits = Quiet @ IntegerDigits @ n},
     FromDigits[Reverse[digits]] /; ListQ[digits]];
```

is not compilation-friendly. This weakness may be addressed by a future version of the compiler.